# drawing app throws memory warning in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I am developing an `iPad` **paint** application.In my application there is a `sketch book` on which the user can draw `sketches` in any page.I have done drawing sketches by identifying user `touches`.In the application,I am detecting `swipe gesture` (up/down) and turn pages one by one using `curl` page transition animation & I have successfully implemented it.

Now the problems are:

1.There comes a conflict between my drawing and turning pages as both of them are analyzing user `finger touches`.(For eg: When I draw with a pen from bottom to top,the swipe gesture detects the swipe event and immediately turns the page.Similarly when I try to swipe a page,sometimes the app draws a stroke on that portion).I would like both of them work at the same time.Is there any way?

2.A user can create N number of drawing in the application.And currently what I have done is,to save current drawing once the user turns the page or tries to navigate away from the screen(in order to use minimum memory).When the next/previous page is about to load,the app will get the proper image from cache directory and loads it.(Previously I kept each of these drawings in an array by fetching every drawings from cache directory.).I am maintaining a database to store the IDs of each drawing and uses this id to read the image from cache directory.The problem is that,After using a couple of minutes(say 5 or 10) the app still throws memory warning.Is there anyway to avoid that?

I have tried to compress images to resolve memory warnings,but the compression makes the images somewhat weird.I am using https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView for normal paint strokes and there is another paint tool that uses `OpenGL` for specific type of stroke.

Answer (score 0):

I think without code it will difficult to predict where the memory leak is . The best option is to profile your application. Go to **product -> Profile (window + I)**. Now you can see which of the variable taking the memory .

Note : if you are using ARC then garbage collector will take care of releasing the memory .
If you are allocating the some memory using **malloc** or **calloc** its your responsibility to release that memory .

Comment: I am using ARC & still I am getting a lot of memory issues.I tried profiling and the top one that uses memory is Image_IO_PNG_Data & second one is CG Raster data.I am not using malloc or calloc in my code.Apart from that, is there any way to resolve my first issue as well?